# Why does include('php://input') not work?

Tags: php, security

Imagine a toy PHP application vulnerable to absolute local file inclusion, e.g.

```
<?php include($_GET['action']);
```

I tried the following request to exploit it:

```
POST /?action=php://input HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Length: 3

foo
```

This effectively executes `include('php://input');` with request body `foo`, so I would expect it to print `foo`. However, I get the following error

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(php://input): failed to open stream: operation failed in <b>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(): Failed opening 'php://input' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in <b>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
```

What is the issue here? Is this a PHP security feature? If so, can somebody point to the responsible part of the PHP source code that mitigates this?

Comment: What about custom streams? Using `stream_wrapper_register` and all that jazz?

Comment: Check the value of this option in your configuration http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: @Halcyon I'm listening. There's no way I have found this exploitable on a modern LAMP setup except if you have a file-write primitive (such as `session_start()` or application-specific logging etc.)

Comment: @Gustek Oh I see. The docs for the `php://` stream wrapper say "Restricted by allow_url_include php://input, php://stdin, php://memory and php://temp only.". I assumed `php://` in general would work because something `php://filter` is enabled :) I guess that resolves the issue

Comment: You can follow the logic for `include` and `require` starting at  [`open_file_for_scanning`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#L495-L568).

Comment: @bishop nice, thanks

Comment: @bishop Actually I think that code comes into effect only after you already have an open file handle

Comment: Oh? `open_file_for_scanning` takes a [`zend_file_handle`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_stream.h#L65-L75), which contains the path, stream type, and a union that includes a file handle proper (eg `FILE *`). That union isn't populated until `zend_stream_open` is called, which is done by `zend_stream_fixup` on line 508 inside of `open_file_for_scanning`. Yes?

Comment: @bishop Oh ok maybe I missed something

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer with the help of [Gustek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857533/gustek). Apparently `php://input` falls under the restrction of `allow_url_include`, while for example `php://filter` does not:

> Restricted by allow_url_include:  php://input, php://stdin, php://memory and php://temp only.

Source: [Docs for `php://` URL handler](http://php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php#refsect1-wrappers.php-options)